# Login into Shopify using php curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to login into shopify account using curl by posting username and password credentials.
here's my code.

```
$username = "someEmail";
$password = "somePassword";
$url="https://******.myshopify.com/admin/auth/login"; 
$cookie_file_path ="cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'login='.$username.'&password='.$password);
print_r(curl_exec($ch));
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);
curl_close($ch);
```

Currently when i execute this, no login is happening, instead it is showing "You have been redirected", and when clicked on that link it'll go to the login page of shopify.

Comment: Better use this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('login'=>$username, 'password'=>$password);` And `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, True);`

Comment: @gofr1 `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` should be the answer

Comment: Tried that and changed CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to true..But still its not working. Just navigating to the login page asking for username and password.     thanks

Comment: @Vaviloff Yes. My comment about `postfields` is just a matter of habit :)

Comment: Make sure about your post fields and change it `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` , check post data from your inspect element

Comment: And how about adding `CURLOPT_POSTREDIR`?

Comment: @gofr1 No, I meant why not post that comment as the answer? The issue most probably was in forbidden redirect :)

Comment: @Vaviloff Apparently, this did not solve the problem.

Comment: @PhpBud, check if `cookie.txt` file exists and contains data. `Just navigating to the login page asking for username and password` sound like a session loss problem.

Comment: @PhpBud you won't be able to login using curl.

Comment: if nothing else, you're missing the authenticity_token on your request here.